# Why does ZSH keep running after exiting a process with CTRL-C, until CTRL-C is pressed again?

Tags: macos, bash, terminal, zsh

I am using zsh on OS X 10.15.3, and am running into the odd problem that whenever I terminated a process (like a Node.JS app) using CTRL-C, the app is shut down fine, but the terminal then remains in a weird state where zsh is still running in the background somehow.

Output is:

```
^C
Adam@Adams-2020-MacBook-Air server %
```

If I try to close the window, OS X will prompt me: "*Do you want to terminate running processes in this tab? Closing this tab will terminate the running process -zsh*"

The terminal looks as if the app has been shut down and nothing else is running, but when I press keyboard up or down (to try and find my last command), the terminal will output them as characters `^[[A^[[B`:

```
^C
Adam@Adams-2020-MacBook-Air server % ^[[A^[[B
```

Only after I press CTRL-C again, a second time, does the terminal appear to properly close all processes.

```
^C
Adam@Adams-2020-MacBook-Air server % ^[[A^[[B^C
Adam@Adams-2020-MacBook-Air server %  <-- now keyboard up/down works as expected
```

With other terminals, and previous versions of OS X, I used to press CTRL-C once to shut down the app process, and I could then immediately start typing new commands and use the keyboard up/down arrows without having to CTRL-C a second time.

Questions:

1. Why is this happening?
2. Why is the "zsh" process launched after I stop another process with CTRL-C?
3. How do I stop this from happening?

**Further information**

Output from `ps lww` when in bad state:

```
ps lww
  UID   PID  PPID CPU PRI NI      VSZ    RSS WCHAN  STAT   TT       TIME COMMAND
  501  1038  1037   0  31  0  4334096    624 -      S+   s000    0:00.47 -zsh
  501 47069 47068   0  31  0  4334096   1040 -      S+   s001    0:00.03 -zsh
  501   438   435   0  31  0  4334096    708 -      S    s008    0:00.07 -zsh
  501 16686   438   0  31  0  4634128  17048 -      S+   s008    0:07.80 node /Users/Adam/.yarn/bin/yarn.js start
  501 16727 16686   0  31  0  4590112  14972 -      S+   s008    0:00.23 /Users/Adam/.n/bin/node /Users/Adam/Sites/helloclub/client/node_modules/.bin/run-p serve watch
  501 16728 16727   0  31  0  4633296  17468 -      S+   s008    0:07.82 /Users/Adam/.n/bin/node /Users/Adam/.yarn/bin/yarn.js run serve
  501 16729 16727   0  31  0  4633296  17492 -      S+   s008    0:07.81 /Users/Adam/.n/bin/node /Users/Adam/.yarn/bin/yarn.js run watch
  501 16730 16729   0  31  0  4984048 113904 -      S+   s008    3:56.33 gulp watch  
  501 16731 16728   0  31  0  4654396  50488 -      S+   s008    0:57.83 /Users/Adam/.n/bin/node build/serve.js
  501 16732 16731   0  31  0  4379808   4644 -      S+   s008    0:00.11 open -W http://localhost:8080
  501   450   447   0  31  0  4334096   1512 -      S    s009    0:00.13 -zsh
```

It appears to happen when using `yarn` to start a script in combination with `nodemon`. Running a script with `yarn` alone does not seem to cause any issues, nor does running a script with `nodemon` directly. Somehow the two combined are causing a problem.

Comment: It's something specific to your system. You may need to look at your shell startup scripts, or how you're invoking node.js or whatever, to see if you're invoking it in a way that invokes it within a subshell. It would also be helpful to see the output of "ps lww" when in the bad state.

Comment: @Spiff I have added the output of `ps lww` there. You may be right though, the common denominator appears to be scripts that are launched with `nodemon`. I will investigate that angle further.

Comment: Possibly related: https://github.com/remy/nodemon/issues/1326

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem with the -zsh prompt when exiting the terminal, one way I solved it is went to `.zshrc` and found `module_init` had been added inside it, which had been added after I installed a malicious software, I edited the file and removed the line `module init` in `~/.zshrc` so it stops running a process, and if this was your problem, go ahead and delete the script `module init` inside `~/.zsh/misc/module_init`.
And I know this is not an acurate answer but I can't comment because I'm new